# Graphical representation of a puzzle

Tags: graphics, common-lisp

Just for fun, I have written a [solver](https://github.com/MartinBuchmann/cl-str8ts) for [str8ts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Str8ts) puzzles. While dealing with the `REPL` representation of a puzzle is okay for me, e.g.

```
STR8TS> (solve-puzzle #p"puzzles/2019-02-04-hard")
Initial puzzle:
 -----------------------------------------------------
|  -7 |  -9 |   0 |   0 |  10 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  10 |
|   3 |   0 |   6 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  10 |
|   0 |   0 |  10 |   0 |   0 |  10 |  10 |   0 |   0 |
|   0 |   1 |   0 |  10 |  10 |   0 |   0 |   5 |   0 |
|  10 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  10 |
|   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  -6 |  10 |   0 |   9 |   0 |
|   0 |   0 |  10 |  10 |   0 |   0 |  -2 |   0 |   0 |
|  10 |   0 |   9 |   0 |   0 |   5 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  -4 |   0 |   0 |   0 |  10 |   0 |   0 |  -1 |  -3 |
 -----------------------------------------------------
Final state:
 -----------------------------------------------------
|  -7 |  -9 |   5 |   6 |  10 |   2 |   3 |   4 |  10 |
|   3 |   8 |   6 |   5 |   7 |   1 |   4 |   2 |  10 |
|   1 |   2 |  10 |   7 |   8 |  10 |  10 |   6 |   5 |
|   2 |   1 |   3 |  10 |  10 |   7 |   8 |   5 |   6 |
|  10 |   6 |   4 |   3 |   5 |   8 |   9 |   7 |  10 |
|   5 |   3 |   2 |   4 |  -6 |  10 |   7 |   9 |   8 |
|   6 |   5 |  10 |  10 |   3 |   4 |  -2 |   8 |   9 |
|  10 |   4 |   9 |   8 |   2 |   5 |   6 |   3 |   7 |
|  -4 |   7 |   8 |   9 |  10 |   6 |   5 |  -1 |  -3 |
 -----------------------------------------------------
Puzzle solved in 4.168 seconds.
```

I was wondering what could be a more elegant way to /draw/ the puzzle. The puzzle is stored in a two-dimensional array and `10` and negative number should be black fields.

Is there a library which allows for the generation of a simple png or svg file of the puzzle grid in b/w and the numbers as text?

Comment: I’ve always used cairo (cl-cairo2) and/or sdl for such things. Not sure if there’s a better way

Comment: As far as I understand that’s for actually drawing a live picture, isn’t? I was thinking about creating a static picture in a file.

Comment: Cairo can render to PNG and SVG files too.

Comment: Great! Then I will have a deeper look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Vecto](https://xach.com/lisp/vecto/) for things like that. It's fairly low-level (kind of like writing PostScript code), but lets you draw stuff like the [Movie Charts](https://xach.com/moviecharts/2018.html), so it's a matter of planning and practice to make what you like.